# Is there a way to tell if a Dropbox chunk upload commit was successful?

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox-api

At the end of a chunk upload, I use the following command to commit the file:

```
self.restClient.uploadFile(filename, toPath: destDir, withParentRev: nil, fromUploadId: uploadId)
```

Can this commit fail? Is there a success or error method that is run when this method returns?

Comment: Linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203865195-File-Chunk-Upload-Commit-on-iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

€dited: there are a couple of delegate methods you can use

```
    func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, loadedFile destPath: String!, contentType: String!, metadata: DBMetadata!) {
        NSLog("File DOWNLOADED successfully to path: %@", destPath);
    }

    func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, loadFileFailedWithError error: NSError!) {
        NSLog("File DOWNLOAD failed with error: %@", error)
    }

    func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, uploadFileFailedWithError error: NSError!) {
        NSLog("File UPLOAD failed with error: %@", error)
    }
```